# How can I properly load a value saved to a user's browser with useCookies in React Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I've set up a basic program for understanding how to save/load cookies in React and alter the loaded value. I have a class App.tsx where the user can click a button to increase a number:

```
function App() {
  let [myNumber, setMyNumber] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{myNumber}</p>
      <Save myNumber={myNumber.toString()} />
      <button onClick={() =>setMyNumber(myNumber+1)}>Click</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Each time the button is clicked, the number increases by one and it is sent to the save class, Save.tsx:

```
type SaveItems = {
    myNumber?: string;
}

const Save: FC <SaveItems> = ({myNumber}) => {
    const [cookies,setCookies] = useCookies(['cookie-number'])

    useEffect(() => {
        if (Number(myNumber)!==0) {
            setCookies('cookie-number',myNumber, { path: '/' })
        }        
    });

    return (
        <>
        
        </>
    )
}

export default Save;
```

This correctly saves the number as a string. I have another class built to Load the value, Load.tsx:

```
export default function Load() {
    const [myCookies] = useCookies(['cookie-number']);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(myCookies['cookie-number']);
    },[])

    return (
        <>
            <p>{myCookies['cookie-number']}</p>
        </>
    )

}
```

This correctly Loads in the saved value, but I also want that value to be set to myNumber in App.tsx, if there is a saved value so I can continue to increase whatever was saved.

In trying to solve this issue, I set up a useEffect hook in my App.tsx and set the value like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setMyNumber(Load().props.children.props.children);
},[])
```

However, this gives me and invalid hook call error. I then tried to insert the value that returns from the Load class into my return statement in App.tsx: `<Save myNumber={Load()} />` but that gives me the error that elements can't be set as a string.

Edit:  Also, if in App.tsx i create the myNumber like so: `let [myNumber, setMyNumber] = useState(Number(Load().props.children.props.children));' it loads the saved value, but if there is no saved value it says the value is NaN and cannot be added to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While React components can include code with side-effects (such as saving a cookie), it's a little unusual to have a component such as `Save` which acts only to run the side-effect and doesn't render anything.

You'll also find that there is no external access to the rendered output of components from within the component tree, which is why `Load().props.children.props.children` is failing.

A better fit is to [write your own hook(s)](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/reusing-logic-with-custom-hooks). These don't render to the component tree, but they can return values.

A direct replacement for your existing code might be something like:

```js
function useSaver(myNumber: number) {
    const [cookies,setCookies] = useCookies(['cookie-number'])

    useEffect(() => {
        if (Number(myNumber)!==0) {
            setCookies('cookie-number',myNumber, { path: '/' })
        }
    }, [myNumber]);
}

function useLoader() {
    const [myCookies] = useCookies(['cookie-number']);

    return myCookies['cookie-number'];
}

function App() {
  const initialNumber = useLoader();
  let [myNumber, setMyNumber] = useState(initialNumber ?? 0);

  useSaver(myNumber.toString());

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{myNumber}</p>
      <button onClick={() =>setMyNumber(myNumber+1)}>Click</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```